# My images are stacking one over the other (CSS) and taking more space outside the designed website

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My content images are stacking over one another, and I have set max width yet they take up more space than the desired. My other image under the heading is also taking up more space than the website designed. I tried deleting the .image selector in css but nothing changed.

```css
* {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e5e7eb;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 8px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.header {
    background-color: #1f2937;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.heromain {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #f9faf8;
}

.herotwo {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #e5e7eb;
}

.section-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #f9faf8;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.content {
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: #1F2937; 
   text-align: center;
}

.quote {
    background-color: #e5e7eb;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #1f2937;
    padding: 100px 300px;
}

.action, button {
    background-color: #3882f6;
    color: white;
}

.action {
    width: 650px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 30px 100px;
}

button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 4px 17px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

footer {
    background-color: #1F2937;
    color: #e5e7eb;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 100px;
}

.info {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: #3882f6;
    border-width: 4px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.information {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
}

.image {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header2">
          <div class="logo">Header Logo</div>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">header link one</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">header link two</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">header link three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="section-left">
            <div class="heromain">This website is<br>awesome</div>
            <div class="herotwo">This website has some subtext that goes here under the <br>main title. It is a smaller font and colors contrast.</div>
            <button>Sign up</button>
          </div>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="image.png">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Some random information.</div>
    <div class="information">
        <div class="info">
            <img src="image.png" alt="img">
            <div class="text">this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="image.png" alt="img">
            <div class="text">this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="image.png" alt="img">
            <div class="text">this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="image.png" alt="img">
            <div class="text">this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="quote">This is an inspiring quote, or a testimonial from a customer.
        Maybe its just filling up space, or maybe people will actually read it. Who knows? All I know is that it looks nice.
        <div class="attribution">-Thor, God of Thunder</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <p><strong>Call to action! It's time!</strong><br>
        Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!
        </p>
        <button>Sign up</button>
    </div>
    <footer>Copyright © The Odin Project 2021</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[The desired outcome for my images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1DMl.png)

The outcome I am getting:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmfuI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one**:

you can fix that by adding bootstrap to your project, for example you want 3 picture be next each other, try this one and edit that by your image src

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>StackOverFlow</title>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a short card.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

or if you want 4 picture be next of each other change the md and g ... in line 17

**Solution two**:

or you can fix that with HTML and CSS with class and ... look at this one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Images Side by Side</h2>
<p>How to create side-by-side images with the CSS float property:</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Remember that your pictures size are important too , and your web site it would be better to be responsive because of that i suggest you to use number one, but in the end both of them are useful and you can use them**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.info img {
    max-width: inherit;
  }
```

[image]